# Django - How to show errors on page instead of displaying error 500 page?

Tags: django

I have a Booking model with custom validation. When I submit the form such that the duration is 0 which raises a ValidationError, it directs me to the Django Debug/Traceback page with this message

```
ValidationError at /management
{'__all__': [u'Duration cannot be 0.']}
```

How can I make it so that the message is displayed inline with the form itself?

**models.py**

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    duration = models.FloatField(default=1) # duration in hours
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.duration == 0:
             raise ValidationError('Duration cannot be 0.')
        super(Booking, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super(Booking, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
def management(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
         form = ManagementBookingForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             duration = form.cleaned_data['duration']
             booking = Booking(duration=duration)
             booking.save()
             return redirect('management')
         else:
            context = {}
            context['booking_form'] = form
            messages.error(request, 'Errors were found in the form')
            return render(request, 'bookings/management.html', context)
```

Comment: from where did you import `ValidationError`? are you using `ModelForm` ?

Comment: from django.core.validators. using django.forms produces the same result

Comment: 1. Remove `full_clean` from save method
2. Replace your form with `ModelForm` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/
3. Let the form handle the saving

Comment: Not using ModelForm. I'm using a subclass of forms.Form.

Comment: Is there no other solution? I need the customisability of forms.Form .

Comment: Remove `full_clean` function from model's save and call it from form's clean method instead. Basically ValidationError won't be handled by the form unless its raised somewhere inside the form class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since (for reasons you won't explain) you're not using a ModelForm, you can't rely on the model validation here: you'll need to use form validation. Move the `clean` method to the Form subclass, and import ValidationError from django.forms.